# PDO - FetchAll, LEFT JOIN., remove index values?

Tags: php, mysql

In my web application i fetch some data from table.

I have

```
SELECT * FROM yyy LEFT OUTER JOIN users_experts USING ( xxx )  WHERE yyy.xxx=:xxx
```

That's work just fine.

I download this using PDO

```
 foreach ($b->fetchAll() as $row)
        {
    $row['xxx']=NULL;
    $row['xxxx']=NULL;
    $row['xxxx']=NULL;

}
return $row;
```

And problem is...

```
$row, cointain
$row[1]
$row[2]
$row[3]
```

and

```
$row['clumn_name']
$row['clumn_name_2']
$row['clumn_name_3']
```

As you cann see, i have some important data, what i set to null to prevent displaying.

I'm looking for way, to remove all "number" records.
Is there any good way ?

I just want remove all

```
$row[1]
$row[2]
$row[3]
```

but left

```
$row['something']
$row['something2']
$row['something3']
```

So the problem is.
Mysql, pdo, return not only "names" indexes but also "numeric indexes".
So my question is... how can i remove them.
I know i can write
for `(x<table(items.count)))` and  `$row[$x]=''` 
to just erase all number fields. but maybe there is directive what will prevent from fetching this...
Just adding something, and it will forget about returning that data...

Comment: Please look at the live preview that StackExchange shows you when writing questions & answers. SE doesn't use bbcode; it uses [markdown](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/editing-help). So please format your questions properly in the future to make things more readable.

Answer (score 7):

All PDO fetching methods accept an argument which specifies the desired fetch style. See [the documentation for PDOStatement::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). You can also set a default fetch style for the entire database connection using [PDO::SetAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php).

In this case you can use `$b->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.